# Force Diagram with 2 forces

Tags: javascript, force-layout, d3.js

In v3.x I had a diagram with a central node in the middle and some nodes either on the left or the right-hand side of it. Something like this: 
[image]

Ive used a slightly clunky method, below

```
tick = function () {
nodes.forEach(function (n) {
    if (n.position == "L") {
        n.x -= force.alpha() * 80;
    }
    if (n.position == "R") {
        n.x += force.alpha() * 80;
    }
});...
```

I had a "position" marker on the node object and pushed it to the Right or Left of the central fixed node.
I was wondering whether v4 has to offer something more "built-in" in functionality using `.force("x", d3.forceX()) & .force("y", d3.forceY())` or  `.force("xcenter", d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(0.01))` or some other simulation property in d3.js v4.

Any advice/suggestion would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be a better solution, but you can put the logic of whether the nodes should be on the left/right in the accessor of the forceX function.

edit:

```js
d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force("x",d3.forceX(function(n){
    if (n.position === "L"){
      return l_position
    }else{
      return r_position
    })
   )
```

Comment: Elaborate a bit more on this idea pelase

Comment: Ill give it a go, and come back to you on this. Thanks